# How to open social media apps upon clicking the link on Webview Apps in Android Studion

Tags: android-studio, webview

I've been having trouble concerning opening of social media apps. For instance I'm using Web-view apps, so in my website I have social media links there, but anytime I click the link, it will open the website instead of opening the app.
Please any solution on that.

Comment: Can you post what the code is on your website and what it's supposed to do?

Comment: I don't ur question, but anytime I click on the social link, any social media link, it will open the site, like let me use facebook for in stance, it will open facebook.com instead of redirecting me to Facebook app on my phone, any help to render?

Comment: Ok, my site is https://www.maximhub.com